# How to convert PySpark pipeline rdd (tuple inside tuple) into Data Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a  PySpark pipeline RDD like bellow

```
(1,([1,2,3,4],[5,3,4,5])
(2,([1,2,4,5],[4,5,6,7])
```

I want to generate Data Frame like below:

```
Id  sid  cid
1   1   5
1   2   3   
1   3   4
1   4   5
2   1   4
2   2   5
2   4   6
2   5   7
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an RDD like this one,

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
   (1, ([1,2,3,4], [5,3,4,5])),
   (2, ([1,2,4,5], [4,5,6,7]))
])
```

I would just use RDDs:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda rec:
    ((rec[0], sid, cid) for sid, cid in zip(rec[1][0], rec[1][1]))
).toDF(["id", "sid", "cid"]).show()

# +---+---+---+
# | id|sid|cid|
# +---+---+---+
# |  1|  1|  5|
# |  1|  2|  3|
# |  1|  3|  4|
# |  1|  4|  5|
# |  2|  1|  4|
# |  2|  2|  5|
# |  2|  4|  6|
# |  2|  5|  7|
# +---+---+---+
```